# onsen ui problems with carousel

Tags: jquery, angularjs, onsen-ui

I have the following carousel
 
with some  inside 
but when i try to use in my controller mycarousel.getActiveCarouselItemIndex()
the app says Uncaught ReferenceError: mycarousel is not defined

Please help me, Im new in onsen. Thanks.

Comment: Seems like you copypasted code and did not even defined mycarousel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define the carousel you can assign it to a variable by using

```
<ons-carousel var="mycarousel">
  ...
</ons-carousel>
```

It will be attached to the variabled `window.mycarousel`.

Another way to get the object is to listen for the `ons-carousel:init` DOM event:

```
document.addEventListener('ons-carousel:init', function(e) {
  var mycarousel = e.component;
});
```